# Outline of a proof that $\mathbb{R}^2 - A$ where A is countable is path-connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**Let $A$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $\mathbb{R}^2-A$ is path connected.**

These are my steps:

1. Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary points of $R^2$
2. Let $f^r:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f^r(t)=(1-t^r)x+t^ry$ for $r \in\mathbb{R}$.
3. Show that $f^r$ is a continuous path between $x$ and $y$ and that non of them intersect.
4. Show that $f^r$ is bijective with $\mathbb{R}$ through $F(f^r)=r$ and conclude that there are uncountable non intersecting paths.
5. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $A$ intersects all of the paths $f^r$ and deduce that $A$ must be uncountable (since it must intersect every $f^r$ at a different point).
6. Contradiction! ($A$ is countable) Hence there exist a paths $f^r$ for some $r \in\mathbb{R}$ which doesn't intersect $A$.
7. $\mathbb{R}^2-A$ is path-connected.

Is this proof sound?

Comment: Yes, it is. See also the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155952/arcwise-connected-part-of-mathbb-r2).

Comment: The first half of 4 is formulated a bit oddly, but apart from that it is fine.

Comment: @Dimitris $A$ having measure $0$ is not sufficient.  For example, if we take $A = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, the resulting set is not path connected, even though $m(A) = 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom,corrct.thnx

Comment: @Dimitris it is, however, sufficient to require that $A$ be the continuous image of some $1$-dimensional measure-zero set, as explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77791/separation-of-two-points-with-null-sets)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom,somehow this is what i wanted to say.i haven't studied yet measure theory. i will start this semester:P

Comment: Half of your maps $f^r$ have exactly the same image: the straight line segment connecting $x$ and $y$. Others do no make sense: for example, when $r<0$. Others are in fact constant (when you deal appropriately with the fact that $0^0$ is not defined...) You need to make sure that things you write do make sense! In particular, youe argument —while well-oriented— is quite not sound.

Comment: (You need to take $x$ and $y$ *distinct* for any chance of your claims to be true. Even in that case, it is impossible to have two distinct paths from $x$ to $y$ have distinct images, for the two points will allways be in the intersection)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I see now that in my notebook i only really considered $r \in R_{+}$ thanks for pointing that out! What i meant implicitly by distinct path is distinct with regard to points other than x and y.

Comment: If you restrict to $r>0$ all the maps have **exactly** the same image. (It is never a good idea to «mean something implicitly»: be explicit.)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez There must be something fundamental I’m not seeing here because $f^{1/2}(t)$ can't possibly be a straight line. Could you please write a more detailed answer explaining this?

Comment: I don't know why it cannot possibly be a straight line, since it is :-) I suggest you make pictures of the images of your functions $f^r$ for various values of $r$ (fix $x=(0,0)$ and $y=(1,0)$, for example)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I see now! thanks for making me feel retarded :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof fails since as Mariano in the comments pointed out:

For $x=(0,0)$ and  $y=(0,1)$, $f^r(t) = (0,t^r)$ which is a straight line (and obviously intersects the other paths).

A great sound proof of this statement can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155952/arcwise-connected-part-of-mathbb-r2).

ADDED: Mariano found a way to fix the argument:

instead of step (2): Let $v$ be a non zero vector orthogonal to $y-x$ define $f^r$ as follows:
$$f^r(t)=x+t(y-x)+rt(1-t)v \space \space \space \space \space r \in (0,1)$$

It follows that if $f^{r_1}(t)=f^{r_2}(t)$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$  and some $t,r_1,r_2 \in(0,1)$ then:

$$x+t(y-x)+r_1t(1-t)v = x+t(y-x)+r_2t(1-t)v$$

$$\implies (y-x)+r_1(1-t)v = (y-x)+r_2(1-t)v$$

By orthogonality of $v$ and $y-x$ $\implies r_1(1-t)=r_2(1-t)$

$$\implies r_1=r_2$$

Namely we've shown that if two paths intersect at one point (other than $t=0,1$) then they correspond to the same parameter $r$.

instead of step (4): show that $f^r$ is bijective with (0,1) and hence uncountable.

change in step (6): $r \in (0,1)$

Comment: You *can* fix your argument! For example: let $v$ be a non-zero vector orthogonal to $y-x$, and consider the functions $f^r:t\in[0,1]\mapsto x+t(y-x)+r t(1-t)v\in\mathbb R^2$, for each $r\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Fixed!

Comment: @SaalHardali : I don't understand one thing , from $x+t(y-x) + r_1t(1-t)v=x+t(y-x)+r_2t(1-t)v$ , by cancellation of addition of vectors , doesn't it follow that $r_1t(1-t)v=r_2t(1-t)v$ and $v$ is non-null , so $r_1t(1-t)=r_2t(1-t)$ , and if $t \in (0,1)$ then $t(1-t) \ne 0$ , so $r_1=r_2$ ? Am I missing something ? Why the orthogonality of $\theta \ne v$ with $y-x$ is needed to deduce this $r_1=r_2$ ?

Comment: Orthogonality isn't really needed only linear dependence.

Comment: @SaalHardali : I can feel that linear independence is needed , we need a vector $v$ that is not a scalar multiple of $x-y$ (otherwise $\mathbb R \setminus A$ also would be path connected ) , but where is it needed in the proof , that I cannot understand ....

Comment: @SaalHardali : Ah huh ! that shouldn't both be $t$ on both sides of your equation , that should be $x+t_1(y-x)+r_1t_1(1-t_1)v=x+t_2(y-x)+r_2t_2(1-t_2)v$ for some $t_1,t_2 \in (0,1)$from which $(t_1-t_2)(y-x)+(r_1t_1(1-t_1) - r_2t_2(1-t_2) ) v=0$ now since $v , y-x$ are linearly independent , so $t_1=t_2$ and $r_1t_1(1-t_1)=r_2t_2(1-t_2)=r_2t_1(1-t_1)$ , so $r_1=r_2$